# Find similar elements of a vector and modify everything inbetween

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, error-handling, rollapply

I have a large data frame (df) with binomial values ranging from 1 to 2. NAs are also included in the data. As a practical example, I will create a short vector containing a subset of a user's data:

```
df <- c(NA,NA,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,NA,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2)
```

What I would basically like as an outcome is a function that searches for the first and the second `2`s of an array and transforms everything within this interval to a 2. Nevertheless, if the difference between the positions of the second and the first 2 are > 3  then the values stay as they are and no change is performed.

In addition to the above, the function has to loop for each value of `df`. For example, considering again the case of:

```
df <- c(NA,NA,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,NA,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2)
```

The function should have this outcome:

```
df_outcome <- c(NA,NA,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,NA,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2)
```

Notice that in `df_outcome` the values between the very first and second 2's were not merged as the difference in their position was >3. On the other hand, other non-2 values were changed accordingly.

What I have tried to do (but it does not work properly):

With the help of `rollapply` in the `zoo` package, I have tried to create a function that finds the first and the second 2 of the array and performs the modifications as described above.

```
func <- function (q) {
  for (i in (which(q %in% 2)[1]):(which(q %in% 2)[2])) {
    q[i]<-2
  }
  return(q)
}
```

Then I nested it using `rollapply`so I can specify a specific width for each cycle plus other arguments such as the position of the result index (left).

```
df_outcome<-rollapply(df, width = 3, FUN = func, fill = NA, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
```

The problem is that the user-generated function works if applied to a vector. When nested as an argument in the `rollapply` function however, it returns an error:

> Error in (which(q %in% 2)[1]):(which(q %in% 2)[2]) : NA/NaN argument
>   Called from: FUN(data[replace(posns, !ix, 0)], ...)

I guess there is some mistake from my part in the use of `rollapply` or perhaps the format of the data but I cannot understand what could be the issue. I thought about using `rollapply`because my data is very long and it is generated for different users. Hence, I would need a function that can also split the data with regards to other variables such as `User_ID` (much like the `.variables`argument in `ddply` or `by` in `data.table`.

Looking forward for your support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with `rle`:

```
rldf <- rle(df)
rllag <- c(tail(rldf$values,-1), NA)
rllead <- c(NA, head(rldf$values,-1))

rldf$values[which(rldf$values == 1 & rllag == 2 & rllead == 2 & rldf$lengths < 3)] <- 2

df_out <- inverse.rle(rldf)
```

which gives:

```
> df_out
 [1] NA NA  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  2

> identical(df_outcome,df_out)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This solution to the problem works very well for my set of data and taught me about the use of rle! Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to get the indices of the `2` in `df`.
Then get the difference between those position and thus find the indices of values to replace by `2`:

```
# position of the 2s
pos_df_2 <- which(df==2) 
# which of the difference in positions are less than 3
wh_pos2_inf3 <- which(c(FALSE, diff(pos_df_2)<=3))
# get all indices between positions that are separated by less than 3 elements
ind_to_replace <- unique(unlist(sapply(wh_pos2_inf3, function(x) {pos_df_2[x-1]:pos_df_2[x]}))) 
# replace the elements by 2
df[ind_to_replace] <- 2 
df
#[1] NA NA  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually thought about the use of indices and your solution provides a clear answer from this perspective. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` (but there's maybe a far better solution):

```
df<-c(NA, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
dt<-data.table(val=df)
dt[,`:=`(id=rleid(val), p=shift(val,type="lag"), n=shift(val,type="lead"))]
dt[,`:=`(s=.N, f=p[1], e=n[.N]), by=id]
dt[f==2 & e==2 & s<3, val:=2]
```

In details:

Create `df` with a small difference to have two consecutive 1 in the test data

```
df<-c(NA, NA, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
  1, 1, 2)
dt<-data.table(val=df)
```

Create a `rleid` of val, lag and lead the val (for next step)

```
dt[,`:=`(id=rleid(val), p=shift(val, type="lag"), n=shift(val, type="lead"))]
```

Then by id (group) get the size of the group, previous and next value for this group

```
dt[,`:=`(s=.N, f=p[1], e=n[.N]), by=id]
```

Now filter per your requirements (previous an next is 2, size less than 3) and set the val to 2

```
dt[f==2 & e==2 & s<3, val:=2]
```

Which gives at end

```
dt[,val]
[1] NA NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1 NA  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  2
```

Compared to source:

```
[1] NA NA  2  1  1  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1 NA  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  2
```

It seems to give what you're expecting.

Comment: It took me some time to understand this but it does wonders - thanks. I do not have much experience with data.table so I am looking forward to get into it a bit more. Thanks for the thorough explanation.